# Sqlalchemy on SQL Server adding space to column varchar

Tags: sqlalchemy

I am using sqlalchemy version 1.1.11 , to connect to sql sever 2012 everything is good except , I have column which is VARCHAR(15) I check the
length of values in db and they are correct 'KGH' is 3.
When I do select with sqlalchemy it will return values 'KGH ' (4) anybody knows about this. I can fix with rtrim(ltrim) but is this is a bug in sqlalchemy

Comment: Please produce a [mcve].

Comment: I checked again and it is pyodbc problem , I open ticket with them

Comment: Interesting. Could you link it here then?